# How to attach React to WordPress project?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-theming

I wanna add react.js to my wordpress project but don't how to so.

Somebody brief me with simple steps ...

Thanks & Regards,
graphypro

Comment: First google hit: http://wp-and-react.com/

Comment: thanks for the feedback Sir but I just wanna know the direction of learning react with wp